# UILabel is penetrating through UIView content which is on top

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, popup, uilabel

I have `UIView` (popupView) which I'm adding it to another `UIView` (superView). This superView contains an `UILabel` with some text in it. Now this `UILabel`'s text is disturbing the popupView content. For better understanding, you can check the attached screenshot (If you check screenshot, you can observe the line in the popup view was breaking with backside `UILabel`s content). Please help me what went wrong in this or do I need to enable any property for `UIView` or `UILabel`.

[image]

Comment: Why duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271633/uilabel-text-below-uiview-is-penetrating-through-view ?

Comment: Why is there the same question but from another account? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271633/uilabel-text-below-uiview-is-penetrating-through-view

Comment: I'm deleting the other question, since we can't add screenshot in that account.

Comment: Well it seems your Label goes over the popup. But hard to tell without a [mre] or at least the code describing the layout.